# How to force trigger aodh alarm action immediately?

Tags: openstack, autoscaling

I have an Openstack Aodh alarm and it will start the action when the memory usage is greater than 85% for one minute. Now **I would like to trigger the action immediately, manually**, which means force the alarm action start even though the condition doesn't reach the limits, but how?

According to the [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/aodh/pike/admin/telemetry-alarms.html), I've tried to set the state of Aodh alarm to `alarm`, but it didn't work, it evaluated the memory usage and do nothing(cause its less than 85%), then set the state back to `ok` again.

Are there any ways to force trigger Aodh alarm action? I would appreciate any help.

Here are the parts of my Aodh alarm:

```
aggregation_method: mean
alarm_actions: [u'trust+http://192.168.0.100:8004/v1/284e047522bd4adfa3aa5109f1c7513b/stacks/corey_test/d9915fd3-5086-4d38-971b-2694c41e8099/resources/rdgw_scaleup_policy/signal']
alarm_id: e6402673-9a8e-4745-a8df-699edd6ab57a
comparison_operator: gt
enabled: True
evaluation_periods: 1
granularity: 60
metric: memory_util
ok_actions: []
repeat_actions: True
resource_type: instance
severity: low
state: ok
state_reason: Transition to ok due to 1 samples inside threshold, most recent: 11.0
threshold: 85.0
type: gnocchi_aggregation_by_resources_threshold
```

**Update 2020/11/04**

The only thing that comes into my mind is to reduce the threshold and evalution_periods temporarily (ex: threshold:1, periods:1), that will force the alarm start scaling, after the new instance is created, recover the threshold and evalution_periods values back. It works but I don't think that is the best method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alarm actions are AFAIU just HTTP POSTs to the URLs listed in 'alarm_actions', so you can do it yourself (provided you have access to that URL).

In your particular case it is clearly a Heat stack scaling action. You should be able to make a HTTP POST to appropriately similar URL - replace `trust+https://<host>:<port>` part with public Heat endpoint (`openstack catalog show orchestration`) and add a valid Keystone token to the request header.

Alternatively, for Heat stack scaling you can use use the `openstack stack resource signal` command (that does effectively the same REST call, just helps you with auth and endpoint discovery) - the stack ID and the resource name are visible in the URL, so in your case it will be `openstack stack resource signal d9915fd3-5086-4d38-971b-2694c41e8099 rdgw_scaleup_policy`

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! However, I found that it can't trigger the policy consecutively, I guess it's blocked by cooldown.

Comment: yes, heat scaling policies usually have a cooldown set, https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Heat::ScalingPolicy-prop-cooldown